# How to replace the number of each element of a matrix with a subscript?

Tags: matrix, subscript

I want to get the matrix as Figure 2. There should be two ways to achieve the result.

1. There is a matrix as Figure 1, and change it to the form of Figure 2.
2. Generating the matrix as Figure 2 directly.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Note：The matrix in Figure 2 is a symmetric matrix

Figure 1

[image]

Figure 2

[image]

Codes

```
{{C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C16},{0,C22,C23,C24,C25,C26},{0,0,C33,C34,C35,C36},{0,0,0,C44,C45,C46},{0,0,0,0,C55,C56},{0,0,0,0,0,C66}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use an indexed variable and you can easily generate the result without the original matrix. The variable `C` is used by Mathematica so use `c` instead. You can display `c` as `C` if desired.

```
Format[c[m_, n_]] := Subscript[C, 10 m + n]
```

(**EDIT:** Or as suggested by LouisB, for larger arrays use `Format[c[m_, n_]] := Subscript[C, Row[{m, n}, " "]]`)

```
(mat = Array[If[#1 <= #2, c[##], 0] &, {6, 6}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(mat2 = Array[If[#1 <= #2, c[##], c[#2, #1]] &, {6, 6}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: When the subscripts are not single digits, a handy format is `Format[c[m_, n_]] := Subscript[C, Row[{m, n}, " "]]`, which puts a little space between the subscripts.

Comment: @LouisB - Thanks. Added edit above

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Table[If[row>col,Subscript[c,col,row],Subscript[c,row,col]],{row,1,6},{col,1,6}]
```

and if you need that formatted to look at then

```
%//MatrixForm
```

As requested, remove the commas

```
Table[If[row>col,Subscript[c,10*col+row],Subscript[c,10*row+col]],{row,1,6},{col,1,6}]
```

but that will break if you have more than 9 columns and rows. You could then try things like `ToString` and `StringJoin` or maybe come up with your own ideas or how to glue together the subscript values.

As requested, try again to turn matrix1 into matrix 2

```
matrix1={
  {C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C16},{0,C22,C23,C24,C25,C26},{0,0,C33,C34,C35,C36},
  {0,0,0,C44,C45,C46},{0,0,0,0,C55,C56},{0,0,0,0,0,C66}};
matrix2=Table[If[row>col,
  Subscript[c,ToExpression[StringDrop[ToString[matrix1[[col,row]]],1]]],
  Subscript[c,ToExpression[StringDrop[ToString[matrix1[[row,col]]],1]]]],
  {row,1,6},{col,1,6}]
```

Check all this very carefully to make certain that it is correct

Comment: Thanks. Can you generate a matrix  without a comma in subscripts? and how to change the matrix in figure 1 to that in Figure 2?

Comment: Thank you. In fact, transforming matrix1 to matrix2 is more difficult than generating a new matrix2 directly, because it involves in becoming numbers to subscripts. Can you show the process of transformation?

Answer (score 2):

```
m0 = UpperTriangularize @ Array[Symbol @ StringRiffle[{"C", ##}, ""] &, {6, 6}];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ m0
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  \text{C11} & \text{C12} & \text{C13} & \text{C14} & \text{C15} & \text{C16} \\
>  0 & \text{C22} & \text{C23} & \text{C24} & \text{C25} & \text{C26} \\
>  0 & 0 & \text{C33} & \text{C34} & \text{C35} & \text{C36} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & \text{C44} & \text{C45} & \text{C46} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{C55} & \text{C56} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{C66} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**1.**

```
rule = ReplaceAll[s_Symbol :> 
   (Subscript @@ (ToExpression @ StringTake[SymbolName @ s, #] & /@ {1, -2}))];

m0b = # + Transpose[UpperTriangularize[#, 1]] & @ Map[rule, m0, {2}];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ m0b
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} & C_{14} & C_{15} & C_{16} \\
>  C_{12} & C_{22} & C_{23} & C_{24} & C_{25} & C_{26} \\
>  C_{13} & C_{23} & C_{33} & C_{34} & C_{35} & C_{36} \\
>  C_{14} & C_{24} & C_{34} & C_{44} & C_{45} & C_{46} \\
>  C_{15} & C_{25} & C_{35} & C_{45} & C_{55} & C_{56} \\
>  C_{16} & C_{26} & C_{36} & C_{46} & C_{56} & C_{66} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**2.**

```
m1 = Array[Subscript[C, Row @ Sort @ {##}] &, {6, 6}];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ m1
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} & C_{14} & C_{15} & C_{16} \\
>  C_{12} & C_{22} & C_{23} & C_{24} & C_{25} & C_{26} \\
>  C_{13} & C_{23} & C_{33} & C_{34} & C_{35} & C_{36} \\
>  C_{14} & C_{24} & C_{34} & C_{44} & C_{45} & C_{46} \\
>  C_{15} & C_{25} & C_{35} & C_{45} & C_{55} & C_{56} \\
>  C_{16} & C_{26} & C_{36} & C_{46} & C_{56} & C_{66} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
m2 = UpperTriangularize @ m1;

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ m2
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} & C_{14} & C_{15} & C_{16} \\
>  0 & C_{22} & C_{23} & C_{24} & C_{25} & C_{26} \\
>  0 & 0 & C_{33} & C_{34} & C_{35} & C_{36} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & C_{44} & C_{45} & C_{46} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C_{55} & C_{56} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & C_{66} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thanks. But the result of **m1** can not be copied to MS Word, taking the $C_{16}$ in **m1** for example, it shows as `Subscript[C, Row[{1, 3}]]` instead of `Subscript[C, 13]`, so can not be used in word as an equation. Why and how to overcome it?

Comment: @likehust, try replacing  `Row @ Sort @ {##}` with `StringRiffle[Sort@{##}, ""]`.